# Compare two XML strings

Tags: c#, asp.net

Given the following sample xml string:

```
<bookstore xmlns="http://www.contoso.com/books">
  <book genre="autobiography" publicationdate="1981-03-22" ISBN="1-861003-11-0">
    <title>The Autobiography of Benjamin Franklin</title>
    <author>
      <first-name>Benjamin</first-name>
      <last-name>Franklin</last-name>
    </author>
    <price>8.90</price>
  </book>
  <book genre="novel" publicationdate="1967-11-17" ISBN="0-201-63361-2">
    <title>The Confidence Man</title>
    <author>
      <first-name>Herman</first-name>
      <last-name>Melville</last-name>
    </author>
    <price>15.11</price>
  </book>
</bookstore>
```

if I changed it like so:

```
<bookstore xmlns="http://www.contoso.com/books">
  <book genre="autobiography" publicationdate="1981-03-22" ISBN="1-861003-11-0">
    <title>CHANGE HERE1</title>
    <author>
      <first-name>Benjamin</first-name>
      <last-name>Franklin</last-name>
    </author>
    <price>10.90</price>
  </book>
  <book genre="novel" publicationdate="2050-11-17" ISBN="0-201-63361-2">
    <title>The Confidence Man</title>
    <author>
      <first-name>Herman</first-name>
      <last-name>Melville</last-name>
    </author>
    <price>15.11</price>
  </book>
</bookstore>
```

I want to get dictionary containing my changes ie:

=> old value, new value

- book1 => title: The Autobiography of Benjamin Franklin | CHANGE HERE1
- book1 => price: 8.90 | 10.90
- book2 => publicationdate: 1967-11-17 | 2050-11-17

How would I do it. any ideas besides having string comparisons??
I tried using [XML Diff](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302294.aspx) but it returns an XML document and no information about node names.

Comment: Can you share the code you have tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

high level concept is like so:

1. create a Book class which implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface
2. parse your xml file into the `IEnumerble` your case dictionary< int,Book> (int is for id)
3. When a book property changes you can then simply access which book which prop changed, and do whatever you want with the changed book e.g add into a new dicitonary

many good example out there, incl. msdn:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx